# SQL Subquery (select data from three tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this query to get data from mysql. Can it be improved? It takes around 0.2s for each query...

I found some other way such as left join but I can't get all data with one query.

---

Or do I need to use two queries?

1. Select p.id, p.post_date, p.post_content, p.post_title, p.post_name, p.guid
2. for loop -> likes_count, dislikes_count, post_views_count, rate where post_id = p.id?

---

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_date, p.post_content, p.post_title, p.post_name, p.guid, 
(SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id = (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = p.id AND meta_key =  "_thumbnail_id")) AS thumbnail_url, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id) FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = p.id) AS term_taxonomy_id, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = p.id AND meta_key =  "likes_count" LIMIT 1) AS likes_count, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = p.id AND meta_key =  "dislikes_count" LIMIT 1) AS dislikes_count, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = p.id AND meta_key =  "post_views_count" LIMIT 1) AS post_views_count, 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = p.id AND meta_key =  "rate" LIMIT 1) AS rate 
FROM wp_posts AS p INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS t ON p.id = t.object_id  
WHERE p.post_status="publish" 
AND p.ping_status="open" 
AND t.term_taxonomy_id = ? GROUP BY p.id LIMIT ?,?
```

---

[EDIT-1]
[Table structure][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69zuH.png)

---

[EDIT-2]
The Output

```
{"id":11111,"post_date":"2016-01-02T05:46:58.000Z","post_content":"contenttttttt","post_title":"titleeeee","post_name":"postname","guid":"1255322","thumbnail_url":"thumb1957.jpg","term_taxonomy_id":"7","likes_count":"1","dislikes_count":"1","post_views_count":"538","rate":"50"}
```

Comment: have you looked as using [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) like **count** or **sum**

Comment: Sample data and table structure would be helpful.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query